# Saved searches in Slack channel?

Tags: slack

Our team has a dedicated slack channel for all team conversations. But since there are multiple conversation threads going on, things like pull requests awaiting reviewers or approvers tend to get lost. I manually search the channel for messages with Github links that require action to be taken.

I was wondering if there is a way to save this search so that I can run it automatically everyday. I know I can check Github directly, but since there are multiple repositories that the team works with, using Slack will be an easier workflow for us. It also helps loop in managers for follow ups and our managers generally do not follow Git respositories.

Comment: I am searching for a way to do the exact same thing for the exact same reason. Alas, I have found the age old internet problem: **someone with the exact same problem and not solutions** 

Comment: Checking in to say that I'm in the same boat in 2022 as well -_-

Comment: This is possible when you open Slack in the browser, i.e., app.slack.com/client

Comment: @Ollie in the web browser is this possible by saving the link as bookmarks after the search?